# Django-Haystack(elasticsearch) Autocomplete giving results for substring in search term

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have a search index with elasticsearch as backend:

```
class MySearchIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable): 
    ... 
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name') 
    name_auto = indexes.NgramField(model_attr='name')
    ...
```

Suppose I have following values in elasticsearch:

```
Cable
Magnet
Network
Internet
Switch
```

When I execute search for `netw`, it returned `Magnet` & `Internet` also along with `Network`. Using some other test cases I think haystack is searching for substring also, like **net** in `netw` as you see in above example.

Here is the code:

```
sqs = sqs.filter(category='cat_name').using(using)
queried = sqs.autocomplete(name_auto=q)
```

Also tried with:

```
queried = sqs.autocomplete(name_auto__contains=q)
```

How can I resolve this and make it working to return only those results that contains exact search term ?

Using django-haystack==2.4.1 Django==1.9.1 elasticsearch==1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Customize your elasticsearch backend settings with [django-hesab](https://github.com/rhblind/django-hesab)

The default settings of django-hesab will return the exact search result.